Children that overflow their parents don't receive tap detection
i am facing an issue when i use a stack and add a child that has a gesture detector and position it outside the parent widget using positioned it doesn't detect gestures anymore , if there is a fix please explain it
thank you .
my code for the problem :
...List<Widget>.generate(
            images.length,
            (index) {
              return Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: deviceWidth / 3.5,
                    width: deviceWidth / 3.5,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onLongPressStart: (details) {},
                      onTap: () async {
                        var imageFile = await pickImage();
                        if (imageFile != null) {
                          images[index] = makeImage(
                              isPlaceholder: false,
                              imageData: await imageFile.readAsBytes());
                          setState(
                            () {},
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      child: images[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: -10,
                    top: -15,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                          shape: CircleBorder(), color: Colors.red),
                      child: InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.white,
                        onTap: () {
                          images.remove(images[index]);
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        child: const IgnorePointer(
                            child: Icon(Icons.delete_forever)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),


This behaviour is intentional. The framework hitTest goes from parent to children, and by default widget don't allow child to receive hitTest when it is outside of the parent's box.
To achieve "outside of box" gesture detection of an overflowed child. You could push the child that would overflow to the Overlay with OverlayPortal and position it with LayerLink.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('LayerLink'),
        ),
        body: const Center(child: Home()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Wrap(
        spacing: 10.0,
        runSpacing: 10.0,
        children: [
          MyImage(color: Colors.blue),
          MyImage(color: Colors.green),
          MyImage(color: Colors.yellow),
          MyImage(color: Colors.orange),
          MyImage(color: Colors.purple),
          MyImage(color: Colors.red),
          MyImage(color: Colors.pink),
          MyImage(color: Colors.teal),
          MyImage(color: Colors.brown),
          MyImage(color: Colors.grey),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyImage({super.key, required this.color});
  final Color color;

  @override
  State<MyImage> createState() => _MyImageState();
}

class _MyImageState extends State<MyImage> {
  int count = 0;
  final controller = OverlayPortalController();
  final link = LayerLink();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.show();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlayPortal(
      controller: controller,
      child: CompositedTransformTarget(
        link: link,
        child: Container(
          color: widget.color,
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            "$count",
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      overlayChildBuilder: (context) {
        return Center(
          child: CompositedTransformFollower(
            link: link,
            followerAnchor: Alignment.center,
            showWhenUnlinked: false,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(shape: CircleBorder(), color: Colors.red),
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.white,
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    count++;
                  });
                },
                child: const IgnorePointer(child: Icon(Icons.delete_forever)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}



the issue that i faced doing your suggested solution is the overlay child builder builds the widget( for example a button that I want to position outside of the parent ) without a size constraint so it just takes so much unneeded space is there a solution to that ? am I doing something wrong ?

Perhaps you forgot to wrap your button(container) with Center? I updated the example to be more similar to your sample code. It also works if you wrap the CompositedTransformFollower with Center/UnconstrainedBox

yeah that was it , it worked beautifully , just one more thing why does center limit the expansion of the overlay child widget? , and does this approach have any significant hit on the performance ?
thank you so much

This shouldn't affect performance in common use cases. https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints#tight-vs-loose-constraints The overlay has a tight restraint, so it forces the child to be big, You could use any widget that gives child a loose constraint, the original positioning doesn't matter.
